# Indexing a series s2 by a series s1 and keep s1 index

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, indexing

I want to construct a series `s3` from two other series `s1` and `s2` as follows:

```
In [130]: s1
Out[130]: 
1    b
2    b
3    c
dtype: object

In [131]: s2
Out[131]: 
a    x
b    y
c    z
dtype: object
```

I want `s3` to have the index of `s1` and the values of `s2` indexed by the values of `s1`, i.e.:

```
In [131]: s3
Out[131]: 
1    y
2    y
3    z
dtype: object
```

So far, I can get close by simply indexing `s2` by `s1`:

```
In [133]: s2.loc[s1]
Out[133]: 
b    y
b    y
c    z
dtype: object
```

But I can't figure out how to reset the index back to that of `s1` (it doesn't seem to be a `reindex` operation). Doing :

```
pa.DataFrame(s2.loc[s1], index = s1.index)
```

doesn't work either and gives:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) `Series` `s1` by `s2`:

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series(['b','b','c'], index=[1,2,3])
s2 = pd.Series(['x','y','z'], index=['a','b','c'])

s3 = s1.map(s2)
print (s3)
1    y
2    y
3    z
dtype: object
```

It is same as [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` from `s2`:

```
d = s2.to_dict()
print (d)
{'a': 'x', 'b': 'y', 'c': 'z'}

s3 = s1.map(d)
print (s3)
1    y
2    y
3    z
dtype: object
```